# Update MySQL DB with PHP from Checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

I am pulling data down from a MySQL table and loading it into a form for editing(updating) a record. Everything is working great until I come the the check boxes. The checkboxes in the form accurately reflect the values in the appropriate columns in the db. But when the person editing changes the checkbox in the edit form it does not pass the data to the database. I have read a ton of checkbox Q&A on stack overflow but don't seem to find what I am looking for. Sorry if this is a redundant Question. Here is the code.

```
<label for="amenities-beach">
<input class="choose" name="amenitiesB" id="amenities-beach" type="checkbox" 
value="<?php echo $row1["amenitiesB"]; ?>" 
<?php echo $row1["amenitiesB"] ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> /> 
&nbsp;Close to Beach</label>
```

Where amenitiesB in:

```
value="<?php echo $row1["amenitiesB"]; ?>
```

is what has been returned from the DB with a SELECT statement with:

```
 $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

But when I change the value in the form and submit it nothing is passed to the variable in the UPDATE statement. Any idea what I am missing? I have 6 of these checkboxes,amenitiesB, amenitiesK, amenitiesS, amenitiesP, amenitiesF, and preferred all with the same code. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You,
Dave

Ok here is the code: Everything else in the form updates fine. I attempt to pass it to:
    $amenitiesB = $_POST['amenitiesB'];
then I put it into the update statement 
    Hotels.amenitiesB='".$amenitiesB."', 
My UPDATE statement is,
    $query="UPDATE Hotels 
    JOIN surfcup_Rates ON Hotels.id = surfcup_Rates.hotelid
    SET Hotels.hotel='".$hotel."',
More columns, then

```
Hotels.amenitiesB='".$amenitiesB."', 
Hotels.amenitiesB='".$amenitiesK."',
Hotels.amenitiesB='".$amenitiesS."',
Hotels.amenitiesB='".$amenitiesP."',
Hotels.amenitiesB='".$amenitiesF."',
Hotels.amenitiesB='".$preferred."',
```

More columns then:

```
WHERE Hotels.id='".$id."'";
```

Comment: The code where you compile and run the UPDATE statement is missing.

Comment: 1. check that the value is embedded in the form properly. 2. check that the value is being passed back to the server when the form's submitted. 3. check that you're building it into your sql statement properly. 4. check that the query actually ran without error

Comment: We need to see more logic in order to help you out.

Comment: That is a bunch of code. Everything else in the form updates fine. I attempt to pass it to:

Comment: Check out my answer below, I think I originally only understood half the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have comes because when a checkbox is unchecked, by default its data is not transmitted to your PHP, and that's why you have problems by having the UPDATE query parameter empty.
So before your update statement you should have:

```
$fieldenabled=(bool)(isset($_POST['CHECKBOXNAME']) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

And call your UPDATE query with that.

EDIT: Of course you can change $_POST with $_GET depending on the sending method of the `<form>`

Comment: Whoa, that's way overkill to produce a boolean value here.  `isset($_POST['CHECKBOXNAME'])` is all you need, it will produce TRUE or FALSE all on its own.  You don't need to cast it to `(bool)`, it's already a boolean... and you certainly don't then need to then test it and return TRUE or FALSE in the ternary operator.

Comment: Yes, you are right theoretically, but I had problems related to that in the past in certain conditions. The comparison can be removed, but the cast to bool does not harm anyways and is definitelly safer if you use === or !==

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I think I get the problem.  When the box is initially unchecked, the  input has an empty value, then when you check it, it passes an empty value in... it will never fill with what you intend the checked value to be.  So, instead you need something like this:

```
<input class="choose" name="amenitiesB" id="amenities-beach" type="checkbox" value="amenity B Selected" <?php echo $row1["amenitiesB"] ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />
```

... don't make the "value" attribute dynamic, or else once it becomes empty it will always be empty.

Original Answer:

I assume when you say "change the value in the form" you mean that you uncheck the checkbox... unchecked checkboxes never send any data when you submit the form.  You check for "unchecked" status by checking to see if the form variable has been passed at all.

For example:

```
if (isset($_GET['amenitiesB'])) {
    // process with the knowledge that "amenitiesB" was checked
}
else {
    // process with the knowledge that "amenitiesB" was unchecked
}
```

If you mean that you somehow dynamically change the "value" of the checkbox to something else, then I'll need to see the code that accomplishes that.

The main purpose of the "value" attribute in a checkbox input is when you're passing the variable as an array:

```
<label for="amenities-beach">
    <input class="choose" name="amenities[]" id="amenities-beach" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row1["amenitiesB"]; ?>" <?php echo $row1["amenitiesB"] ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />
    &nbsp;Close to Beach
</label>
```

... note specifically that I've changed the "name" attribute from "amenitiesB" to "amenities[]", which, if carried through all of your amenities checkboxes, will give you access to them all in your processing script through the $_GET['amenities'] array (or $_POST, if applicable).  Otherwise, there's not much reason to use the "value" attribute of the checkbox input, because you can get all you need just by knowing $_GET['amenitiesB'] is checked (and thus sent with the form) or unchecked (and not sent with the form).

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I don't know if this helps but when the the form originally that loads the record into db the checkboxes enter  a "B" into amenitiesB column or a "K" into the amenitiesK column and so on. So when I pull the data down to be edited I assumed the value would be the same "B", "k" etc. Mainly because the  checkboxes in the edit form reflect the correct checks for the record to be edited. So what you are saying is... the checkboxes in the edit form are simply saying checked or not checked, not the actual value of the column. Am I making any sense at all?

Comment: Any extra context always helps. So, the row is initialized with "amenitiesB" as "B", then you build your form and, after all of the PHP is processed, you get <input class="choose" name="amenitiesB" id="amenities-beach" type="checkbox" value="B" checked="checked" />.  Then you uncheck it, and you want the database to reflect "amenitiesB" = "".  As best I can gather, that should be happening unless there's an error elsewhere in your unposted code. Continued below...

Comment: The problem is then that when the PHP gets processed, when amenitiesB is empty, the checkbox will look like this: <input class="choose" name="amenitiesB" id="amenities-beach" type="checkbox" value="" checked="checked" /> (note the empty value attribute) and no matter how many times you check it, you'll always be passing back an empty value and it will never be checked. Really you should be using a boolean here in the database, and ignore the value attribute in the HTML.